# How to make React nested routes v6 work to display app components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

Hello Stackoverflow community

I am building a simple SPA using react. My navigation for the app would be a unauthenticated public page(like home/about/pricing etc) and a sign in button that the user will click on to be redirected into the app components after authentication using keycloak.

The way I have structured the app is having a parent router that will redirection between public facing files and then another router that will help router inside the app. The problem I am facing is my app router works but no HTML is displayed or no components are displayed (dashboard component not displayed)

My app.js file

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./pages/Homepage";
import AboutPage from "./pages/AboutPage";
import SecuredPage from "./pages/Securedpage";
import PricingPage from "./pages/PricingPage";

function App() {
 return (
   <div>
          <BrowserRouter>
             <Routes>
                  <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
                  <Route path="/about" element={ <AboutPage />}  />
                  <Route path="/pricing" element={ <PricingPage />}  />
                  <Route exact path="/app" element={ <SecuredPage />}  />
                
            </Routes>
           </BrowserRouter>


    </div>
 );
}
export default App;
```

My HomePage.JS contains

```
import React from 'react';
import NavMain from "../components/NavMain";

const Home = () => {

 return (
   <div>
     <NavMain/>
     <h1 className="text-green-800 text-4xl">Welcome to the Homepage. Some more text123</h1>
   </div>
 );
};

export default Home;
```

My NavMain.JS contains

```
          <ul>
               <li>
                 <a href="/">
                   Home
                 </a>
               </li>
               <li>
                 <a href="/about">
                   About
                 </a>
               </li>
                 <a href="/pricing">
                   pricing
                 </a>
               </li> 
               <li>
                 <a href="/app/dashboard">
                   app
                 </a>
               </li>
           </ul>
```

The public facing components work correctly. Once I click on 'app' I am redirected to the keycloak authentication page and from there after login I am on the securepage page component. But it does not render the dashboard component

SecuragePage.js

```
 import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { ReactKeycloakProvider } from "@react-keycloak/web";
import keycloak from "../Keycloak";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboardpage";
import AboutPage from "./AboutPage";
import PrivateRoutes from "../helpers/PrivateRoutes";

import NavHomePage from "../components/NavHomePage";

const Loading = () => <div>Loading...</div>
const Secured = () => {

 return (
   <div>
     <ReactKeycloakProvider authClient={keycloak}
     initOptions={{
        onLoad: "login-required",
      }}
      LoadingComponent={<Loading />} >
          app landing page
        <NavHomePage/>
             <Routes>
                 <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
                     <Route exact path="/app/dashboard" element={ <Dashboard />}  />
                 </Route>
            </Routes>

    </ReactKeycloakProvider>


    </div>
 );
};

export default Secured;
```

Dashboard.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Dashboard = () => {

 return (
   <div>
     <h1 className="text-green-800 text-4xl">Dashboard</h1>
   </div>
 );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

NavHomePage.js

```
<Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
        <Container>
            <Navbar.Brand href="/">Hype</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                      <Nav className="me-auto">
                        <Nav.Link href="/app">Home</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link href="/app/dashboard">dashboard</Nav.Link>
                      </Nav>
                      <Nav className="ml-auto">

                        {!!keycloak.authenticated && (
                             <Nav.Link onClick={() => logoutHelper()}>
                             Logout ({keycloak.tokenParsed.preferred_username})</Nav.Link>)}
                      </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
    </Navbar>
```

PrivateRouters.js

```
const PrivateRoutes = () => {
 const { keycloak } = useKeycloak();

 const isLoggedIn = keycloak.authenticated;
 console.log("checking auth access " + isLoggedIn);
 console.log(keycloak);
 return isLoggedIn ? <Outlet/> : null;
};
```

Comment: It's unclear how these separate code snippets relate to one another. Can you [edit] to provide a better and more complete and comprehensive [mcve] so it's clearer to readers where and how these different components are being rendered? Is `SecuredPage` component in `App.js` the component/JSX in `SecuragePage.js` file? Is `"/app/dashboard"` the route you are trying to reach and render?

Comment: updated with more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SecuredPage` component is rendering descendent routes, so the parent route ***must*** append a wildcard `"*"` route matcher to it's route so descendent routes can be matched and rendered.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
          <Route path="/pricing" element={<PricingPage />} />
          <Route path="/app/*" element={<SecuredPage />} /> // <-- append "*" to path
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Descendent `Routes` components also build their paths relative to any parent `Routes` components, so the descendent path should not include any of the "path prefix" to this `Routes`.

```
const Secured = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactKeycloakProvider
        authClient={keycloak}
        initOptions={{
          onLoad: "login-required",
        }}
        LoadingComponent={<Loading />}
      >
        app landing page
        <NavHomePage/>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
            <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </ReactKeycloakProvider>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you didn't want to use descendent routes you could convert `Secured` into a layout route component.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const KeycloakLayout = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactKeycloakProvider
        authClient={keycloak}
        initOptions={{
          onLoad: "login-required",
        }}
        LoadingComponent={<Loading />}
      >
        <NavHomePage/>
        <Outlet />
      </ReactKeycloakProvider>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
          <Route path="/pricing" element={<PricingPage />} />
          <Route path="/app" element={<KeycloakLayout />}>
            <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
              <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: perfects, thanks! I realized some mistakes in my understanding of routers. I did not have nested routes and also did not use outlet for the components to be renders in children. Thanks! A resrouce that was also useful https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-nested-routes/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

Instead of using  or <Nav.Link>.
You can easily wrap these inside of

```
<Link to='/app'><Nav.Link>Home</Nav.Link></Link>
```

Check example here: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link

Answer (score 0):

No idea why it doesn't work for you, there should be an example that can be debugged. Learn from this youtube-channel how a good example works:

[Youtube tutorial keycloak with react](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q50LxyGtEf0)

Nevertheless, I see some things in your code that shouldn't be done like this anymore:

1. Do not use the react-keycloak/web library. It has not been serviced since 2021 and is no longer needed!
   Check out the youtube links for a good example of keycloak authentication with routing without this react library.
2. Don't use `<divs>` in your code unless absolutely necessary. If you need divs, then use the `<React.Fragments />` or `<></>` for short. Why is that important? If you want to debug your project in a browser in the future, these divs make the code very cluttered and tedious to debug.

For example here:

```
const Home = () => {
 return (
   <> //NO <div> USED
     <NavMain/>
     <h1 className="text-green-800 text-4xl">Welcome to the Homepage. Some more text123</h1>
   </>
 );
};
```

Another code:

```
function App() {
  return (
      //DONT USE DIV HERE. USELESSS
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
          <Route path="/pricing" element={<PricingPage />} />
          <Route path="/app" element={<KeycloakLayout />}>
            <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
              <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```